# Is there a way to show this series converges or diverges by comparison test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that ,we need to show below series diverges by comparison $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac 1n}}$$ I have not a clue for comparison .
I am thankful If you guide me a clue .

Answer (score 8):

Since $n<2^n$ for all natural $n$ (as can be shown by induction), we have $n^{1/n}<2$ and thus
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac 1n}}>\frac12\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n.$$

Comment: :so it is divergent ?

Comment: $$\sum \frac {1}{n^P} , p>1$$ w.r.t p series ...it converges!  I am confuded